# What is dictionary compaction support?

Tags: c#

"Here is the implementation of the dictionary without any compaction support."

This quote is taken from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/03/03/building-a-weakreference-hashtable.aspx

I know jaredpar is a member on here and posts on the C# section. What exactly is "dictionary compaction support"? I am assuming it is some way to optimise or make it smaller? But how (if this is what it is)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that particular post I was refering to shrinking the dictionary in order to be a more appropriate size for the number of non-collected elements.

Under the hood most hashtables are backed by a large array which usually points to another structure such as a linked list.  The array starts out at an initialize size.  When the number of elements added to the hashtable exceeds a certain threshold (say 70% of the number of elements in the array), the hashtable will expand.  This usually involves creating a new array at twice the size and re-adding the values into the new array.

One of the problems / features of a weak reference hashtable is that over time the elements are collected.  Over time this can lead to a bit of wasted space.  Imagine that you added enough elements to go through this array doubling process.  Over time some of these were collected and now the remaining elements could fit into the previous array size.

This is not necessarily a bad thing but it is wasted space.  Compaction is the process where you essentially shrink the underlying data structure for the hashtable to be a more appropriate size for the data.

Comment: an answer straight from the horse's mouth in under 5 minutes... not bad!  +1